# Properties of a function of a harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Suppose that *u* : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is such that, whenever *v* : $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic, so is  *u(v(x))*. What can you say about *u*?

My first inclination is to say that properties of harmonic functions will not apply to *u* since it is not harmonic by definition. If that is correct, would I then only say that *u* is *C(U)* for $U \subset \mathbb{R}$? Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Take any function v that you know is harmonic. Take any function u... well, just any function, really. Try $u(x)=x^2$, to begin with. Plug one into the other. See what happens. Will the result be harmonic?

Comment: The function $v(x) = v(x_1,\ldots,n_n) = x_1$ is enough to do the job.  The composite function $u(v(x))$ is then just $u(x_1)$, and is by hypothesis harmonic. This implies that $x_1\mapsto u(x_1)$ is smooth.  Now compute the second derivative of this function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to compute directly that
$$ \nabla u(v(x)) = u'(v(x)) \nabla v(x), \\
\Delta(u(v(x))) = u'(v(x)) \Delta v(x) + u''(v(x)) (\nabla v(x))^2 $$
The first term is obviously zero, the second term is zero when at least one of its factors is zero, and for each $x$, we can choose a $v$ so that $\nabla v(x) \neq 0$. Hence $u(v(x))$ is harmonic for every harmonic $v$ if and only if $u'' \equiv 0 $.

(In the above, we assume $u$ is sufficiently smooth: otherwise the Laplacian won't make sense anyway.)